# csrf_exempt true on all callbacks

Tags: django, csrf, middleware

I've created some custom middleware for my django rest api to enforce a CSRF security policy of setting custom headers. I've subclassed CsrfViewMiddleware and overriden a few methods to suite my needs, most notably the check_token method. However, I noticed later on that all requests have been coming in with the attribute "csrf_exempt" set to true, even though nowhere have I used the csrf_exempt decorator. I've searched through the django docs to try and figure out why this has been happening to no avail. Here is my custom middleware:

```
class CustomCsrfMiddleware(CsrfViewMiddleware):

    def _reject(self, request, reason):
        logger.warning("Forbidden (%s): %s", reason, request.path)
        return Response(
            {'detail': 'Forbidden', 'reason': reason},
            status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )

    def _check_token(self, request):

        # Get the two relevant pieces of information, the
        # the returned csrftoken in the custom header and the hmac
        try:
            hmac = _get_hmac(request)
        except BadDigest as e:
            raise RejectRequest(e.reason)

        try:
            request_csrf_token = request.META[settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME]
            token_source = settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME
        except KeyError:
            raise RejectRequest(REASON_CSRF_TOKEN_MISSING)

        try:
            _check_token_format(request_csrf_token)
        except InvalidTokenFormat as e:
            reason = self._bad_token_message(e.reason, token_source)
            raise RejectRequest(reason)

        if not _does_match(request_csrf_token, hmac):
            reason = self._bad_token_message("incorrect", token_source)
            raise RejectRequest(reason)

    def process_request(self, request):

        try:
            csrf_secret = self._get_secret(request)
            if csrf_secret is None:
                raise InvalidTokenFormat(REASON_CSRF_TOKEN_MISSING)
        except InvalidTokenFormat:
            _add_new_csrf_cookie(request)
        else:
            if csrf_secret is not None:
                request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"] = csrf_secret

    def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):
        # exempt /hook paths
        print('callback: ', getattr(callback, "csrf_exempt", False))

        return super().process_view(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
```

And my CSRF settings:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30  # 1 month
CSRF_SAMESITE = 'lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://localhost:3000']
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Turns out, django rest framework wraps all views in csrf_exempt in the return statement for the as_view method of APIView. So, my solution was to just create another decorator called csrf_ignore that set a new attribute on the views called csrf_ignore.

```
from functools import wraps


def csrf_ignore(view_func):
    """Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection."""

    # view_func.csrf_exempt = True would also work, but decorators are nicer
    # if they don't have side effects, so return a new function.
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

    wrapper_view.csrf_ignore = True
    return wrapper_view
```

Then added some logic to the process_view function of my middleware:

```
    def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):
        if not getattr(callback, 'csrf_ignore', False):
            setattr(callback, 'csrf_exempt', False)

        return super().process_view(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
```

Now the correct attributes are set and the middleware will check for the csrf protection when it's supposed to.